# Explanation to better performance with worse GPU executing few blocks

Tags: performance, cuda

I have two GPUs and I'm comparing the speedup between them and my CPU running a genetic algorithm.

My implementation on CUDA uses a master-slave approach, that is, each individual of the population is running in parallel with others. With big populations, meaning more blocks running, the best GPU (GTX660) is much faster than the other one (820M) but running small ones I got better performance with the 820M.

In the CUDA C programming guide it's said:

> The number of instructions required to hide a latency of L clock
>   cycles depends on the respective throughputs of these instructions (see Arithmetic
>   Instructions for the throughputs of various arithmetic instructions); assuming maximum
>   throughput for all instructions, it is:
>
> L for devices of compute capability 2.0 since a multiprocessor issues one instruction
>   per warp over two clock cycles for two warps at a time, as mentioned in Compute
>   Capability 2.x,
>
> 2L for devices of compute capability 2.1 since a multiprocessor issues a pair of
>   instructions per warp over two clock cycles for two warps at a time, as mentioned in
>   Compute Capability 2.x,
>
> 8L for devices of compute capability 3.x since a multiprocessor issues a pair of
>   instructions per warp over one clock cycle for four warps at a time, as mentioned in
>   Compute Capability 3.x.
>
> ### 5.2.3 Multiprocessor level

Is this the answer I am looking for? Since the GTX660 has compute capability 3.x, I need more warps running (bigger population) to hide latency compared to the 820M.

It is important to note that I'm using different computers on this test, it may be another reason...

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm suffering with similar problem, NVS 5200M (2.1) is 2x faster than Grid 520 (3.0) when running one of my kernels. I found that double floating point division in one place is responsible for 50% loss in performance but I can't understand why is that because earlier in the code similar operation is being done and it does not hurt the performance that much ...

Comment: Do you have divergent branches? The cost of these could get more expensive with newer GPUs.

Comment: I do have in some kernels, yes. I'll analyze the differences among them in both GPUs

Answer (score -2):

It is hard to say without looking through the algorithm, but I can't think of a good reason why a well written algorithm would be faster on an 820m than a gtx 660.

Wikipedia has the GFlops rating of 820m at 276-366 with memory bandwidth at 16GB/s. The gtx 660 has 1881 GFlops FMA and 144GB/s bandwidth. I don't know of any architectural changes that would account for that large of a discrepancy.

I would advise comparing the results 1 to 1 and making sure they are both producing the same results. If that is the case, I would carefully walk through the tuning guides for each architecture and make adjustments.

820M:
http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/maxwell-tuning-guide/#axzz3bL3OfJ00

660:
http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/kepler-tuning-guide/#axzz3bL3OfJ00

The primary thing I keep in mind when tuning kepler is that global memory accesses are not cached by default in L1.

Good luck.